# Print JSON Data with python where there is no key & value

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, api, python-requests

I'm currently working with some JSON data that is presenting a challenge, i need to print the device name in my script next to the latency float, i can easily print the latency float as there is a key:value , however the device name does not sit the same, therefore i cannot figure out how to print this especially as it changes for each API Url i am looping through to retrieve the data

The data i want to print is `"DEVICE123-Et10"`

See JSON data below,

```
{
  "notifications": [
    {
      "timestamp": "511513234234",
      "path_elements": [
        "Devices",
        "DEVICE1",
        "versioned-data",
        "connectivityMonitor",
        "status",
        "hostStatus",
        "DEVICE123-Et10",
        "defaultStats"
      ],
      "updates": {
        "httpResponseTime": {
          "key": "httpResponseTime",
          "value": {
            "float": 0
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "timestamp": "15153324243",
      "path_elements": [
        "Devices",
        "DEVICE1",
        "versioned-data",
        "connectivityMonitor",
        "status",
        "hostStatus",
        "DEVICE123-Et10",
        "defaultStats"
      ],
      "updates": {
        "packetLoss": {
          "key": "packetLoss",
          "value": {
            "int": 0
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "timestamp": "151522324234",
      "path_elements": [
        "Devices",
        "DEVICE1",
        "versioned-data",
        "connectivityMonitor",
        "status",
        "hostStatus",
        "DEVICE123-Et10",
        "defaultStats"
      ],
      "updates": {
        "latency": {
          "key": "latency",
          "value": {
            "float": 0.238756565643454
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "timestamp": "158056745645645",
      "path_elements": [
        "Devices",
        "DEVICE1",
        "versioned-data",
        "connectivityMonitor",
        "status",
        "hostStatus",
        "DEVICE123-Et10",
        "defaultStats"
      ],
      "updates": {
        "jitter": {
          "key": "jitter",
          "value": {
            "float": 0.03500000213213
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Current code i am using to loop through my URL list and get the latency:

````
     jsonrequest = requests.get(url, cookies=cookies, verify=False).json()
     try:
         print(jsonrequest['notifications'][2]['updates']['latency']['value']['float'])
     except KeyError:
         print(jsonrequest['notifications'][1]['updates']['latency']['value']['float'])```
````

Comment: Since the device name is always second-last in the list, just access list by using the key "path_elements" and then get the second last element. Something like `json_data["path_elements"][-2]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead and wrote a script to do what you wanted. It loops through all the notifications until a "latency" update is found. Then it takes the second-to-last item from the list, since it's always second to last.

```py
import json
import requests

data = requests.get(url, cookies=cookies, verify=False).json()
notifications = data["notifications"]
for notification in notifications:
    if notification["updates"].get("latency"):
        latency = notification["updates"]["latency"]["value"]["float"]
        name = notification["path_elements"][-2]
        print(name, latency)
```

Comment: The above example does not seem to work, my current code which works without the device name looks as follows:
     ` jsonrequest = requests.get(url, cookies=cookies, verify=False).json()
     try:
         print(jsonrequest['notifications'][2]['updates']['latency']['value']['float'])
     except KeyError:
         print(jsonrequest['notifications'][1]['updates']['latency']['value']['float'])`

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what is the error? What's wrong with it?

Comment: Maybe i am using the incorrect syntax however i am unsure how to loop through each url individually with your code, as my JSON data is coming from a list of URLs and not a specific file. Therefore i am using `for url in URLs:` already

Comment: It should still work. I've updated it to make it more clear. What is the error you get with my solution?

Comment: TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict

Comment: Corrected, try now.

Comment: Fantastic it works! many thanks to Alex Osheter, i learnt something new today about nesting loops thanks to you